# Can I choose squad members?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

It seems that the squad members are chosen by the computer using their rank as criteria.

But If I want to change my squad for a specific setup (e.g. My team has 3 snipers and I want only one), what could I do? Is there a way for me to change before a mission (e.g. in the barracks).

Comment: Once you've chosen squad members for one mission, the game will attempt to choose the same members for subsequent missions.

Comment: Correct. It'll only choose new squad members for you if one or more of your previous squad is unavailable due to injury and/or death.

Answer (score 23):

### **You can change your squad at anytime**

Before a mission starts, just left click on the unit that you want to change and remove him. Then you can add any solider you want to your squad.

[image]

---

### Notes

- Your squad will be by default your highest ranks
- If you make any changes, that will become your 'default squad'
- If any of your troop members are unavailable for any reason
  (Wounded/Psi training) they will be replaced by the highest
  ranking troops available